# Pulling files form S3 bucket into local directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Sorry I am new to setting up s3 file transfers.

I managed to pull files from my s3 bucket into my local environment using the following commands:

```
aws s3 sync s3://myBucket myFolder/.
```

I got the following response:

download: s3://myBucket/image.jpg to myFolder\image.jpg

However, there is nothing in myFolder even though the download was successful. How do I locate the actual file that's being downloaded from s3?

Would the AWS CLI command be the right command to pull files or am I totally missing the point here.

Comment: Does `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket` list files? Are you running this on linux?

Comment: are the files empty ? the part `to myFolder\image.jpg`  suggests you run on windows ? can you try to give full path in windows style ?

Comment: @helloV yes there are files. I am running it on Windows

Comment: @FrédéricHenri no there are actual files....I am running it on the AWS power shell CLI....

Comment: @FrédéricHenri the full path -- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PROJECTS

Comment: Can you `cd myFolder` and then do `aws s3 sync s3://myBucket .` ?

Comment: @helloV Okay it worked...I have to use the full fixed path for the files to be transferred..

Comment: so `aws s3 sync s3://bucket C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PROJECTS\ ` should work for you